# SQL Join Where Q

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am not getting the desired results on my select statement.  The join seems to be working but the WHERE on my date range is being completely ignored.  The where statement "WHERE MOPACTIVITY.mopstart BETWEEN sysdate and (sysdate+14)" is ignored completely.  Any thoughts?
Your expertise is greatly appreciated.

Respectfully,
Jonathan Morningstar

```
SELECT
MOPACTIVITY.MOPID,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSERVICEIMPACTED "Type",  
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTATEACTIVITY "State", 
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTATUS "Status",
MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART "SOM", 
MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND "EOM",  
MOPACTIVITY.MOPINTRUSIVE "INTRUSIVE",
MOPACTIVITY.MOPDESCRIPTION,
MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER "MN_USER",
MOPNOTES.MOPNOTE "MN_NOTE" 
FROM mopuser.MOPACTIVITY INNER JOIN mopuser.mopnotes ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID = MOPNOTES.MOPID;
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.*, MOPNOTES.* from mopactivity.MOPNOTES where MOPACTIVITY.MOPID = MOPNOTES.MOPID 
WHERE MOPACTIVITY.mopstart BETWEEN sysdate and (sysdate+14)
AND MOPACTIVITY.MOPINTRUSIVE = 'true'
AND MOPACTIVITY.mopstatus != 'Complete'
AND MOPACTIVITY.mopstatus != 'Cancelled'
AND (mopactivity.mopid not in (select MOPACTIVITY.mopid from mopuser.mopnotes where 
MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Fortenberry%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Dixon%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Fregoso%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Reices%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Walley%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Lions%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Ramesh%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Saravanan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Boominathan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Srinivasan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Sathya%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Sathish%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Malliga%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Yuvaraj%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Prabhu%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Joseph, Gilbert%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Pradeepa%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Veerababu%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Ramanan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Rajesh%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Rajan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Raja%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Vigneshwari%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Govardhan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Gaytan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Sheridan%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Goutham'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Thennarasu%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Santosh%'
OR MOPNOTES.MOPNOTEUSER LIKE '%Brown, W%'))
```

Comment: The query you posted isn't valid. It has two `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: After removing the second where, it still doesn't obey the remaining where clauses.

Comment: If I time the select all the way to where the join ends, it says that the select is invalid.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got **two independent** `SELECT` statements: there's a semicolon delimiting the first `SELECT` from the second one:

```
SELECT
...
FROM mopuser.MOPACTIVITY
  INNER JOIN mopuser.mopnotes
    ON MOPACTIVITY.MOPID = MOPNOTES.MOPID;
                  -- statement delimiter ^
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.*, MOPNOTES.* from ...
```

This multi-statement query, therefore, returns *two* result sets.

Perhaps, you are able to see only the first query's output. The first query, however, is actually the one that *doesn't* have a `WHERE` clause at all: the `WHERE` condition that you are talking about is part of the second `SELECT` statement.

So, you probably need to combine the two queries somehow. If you need help with that, though, that would be an altogether different question (which would need to be asked separately).